# How to configure a service, host and client for using the wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml

I am trying to make a host/client style WCF system that allows multiple clients in any domain to get data from a server running a host. The service is a service library (not a service application), the host is a console application and the client could be any project type and I am using the wsHttpBinding. I need help with configuring all three parts of it. I know it is not really the best question to ask but I have been trying to get this to work for absolutely ages (weeks) with nothing working.

It would be absolutely amazing if someone could tell me how I can configure (not coding the actual service because I have done that, just the configuration of it) the service, host and client to work over any domain with the wsHttpBinding. How can I write the xaml in the three App.config files to make it work because I find this part absolutely impossible to do and I just really want to get it working? What should the three config files look like? Thank you so much for any help you give me.

Comment: Do you mean `xml` in the config files? Typically VS does most of the [work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) on the host side, except that the config will be added to the (unused) library project. You'll then need to copy the entire [`system.serviceModel` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx) across to your host console project's `app.config`. w.r.t. the client, easiest is to launch the host app, and then add a service reference, and then point it to the host's `wsHttpBinding` endpoint - it will create the necessary config in the client app.

Comment: Not that simple wsBinding may require to set up the behavior and the security. Show us the sever configuration of the WCF.

Comment: Yes the XML, specifically the System.ServiceModel section. But I don't have any configuration because I don't know how to do it. It is defaulted to basicHttpBinding but I want to use wsHttpBinding. Would it be easier to do all the configuration in c# code instead of in the xml?